# Spring security: adding "On successful login event listener"

Tags: authentication, spring-security, listener

I'm new to Spring Security. How do I add an event listener which will be called as a user logs in successfully? Also I need to get some kind of unique session ID in this listener which should be available further on. I need this ID to synchronize with another server.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You need to define a Spring Bean which implements [ApplicationListener](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html).

Then, in your code, do something like this:

```java
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent appEvent)
{
    if (appEvent instanceof AuthenticationSuccessEvent)
    {
        AuthenticationSuccessEvent event = (AuthenticationSuccessEvent) appEvent;
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        // ....
    }
}
```

Then, in your applicationContext.xml file, just define that bean and it will automatically start receiving events :)

Comment: Thanks! Just found AuthenticationSuccessEvent but was trying to figure out how to register a listener.

Comment: what about the session ID he was asking about?

Comment: @siebmanb just add `@Autowired HttpSession session` to the listener. Spring will inject a proxy which automagically delegates to the correction session.

Answer (score 51):

The problem with AuthenticationSuccessEvent is it doesn't get published on remember-me login. If you're using remember-me authentication use InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent instead, it works for normal login as well as for remember-me login.

```
@Component
public class LoginListener implements ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event)
    {
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried to achieve this by using auth-success-handler, but faced with this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575860/remember-me-and-authentication-success-handler. Your answer rescued situation!

Answer (score 26):

Similar to Phill's answer, but modified to take Generics into consideration:

```java
public class AuthenticationListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(final AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {

      // ...

  }

}
```

Answer (score 11):

Another way using `@EventListener`

```
@EventListener
public void doSomething(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event) { // any spring event
    // your code 

}
```

Comment: This one is really simple! Like!

Answer (score 10):

In Grails, with Spring Security Plugin, you can do this in Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true

grails.plugins.springsecurity.onAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->

        def session = SecurityRequestHolder.request.getSession(false)
        session.myVar = true

}
```

Comment: Right way to get request in Config.groovy

    def request= RequestContextHolder?.currentRequestAttributes();

Comment: Does anyone know how to get the current logged in user in this event? I am currently using `def springSecurityService = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean 'springSecurityService';
def user = springSecurityService.getPrincipal()` but user is always null. Thank you!
EDIT: Looks like doing def user = event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal() works great!