# How to correctly update the login date time after successful login with Spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring 3.2.0 and the same version of Spring security. On successful login, a user is redirected to one of the protected pages as follows.

```
public final class LoginSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler
{
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN"))
        {
            response.sendRedirect("admin_side/Home.htm");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Hibernate. How  can I update the login date-time (Last Login) in the database on successful login? I have a submit button on the login page whose `POST` request doesn't seem to map to a method in its corresponding login controller. The login form's action is actually mapped to the Servlet - `j_spring_security_check`.

---

The entire `spring-security.xml` file is as follows, if it is required.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http pattern="/Login.htm*" security="none"></http>    

    <http auto-config='true'>
    <!--<remember-me key="myAppKey"/>-->
        <session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
        </session-management>

        <intercept-url pattern="/admin_side/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" requires-channel="any"/>
        <form-login login-page="/" default-target-url="/admin_side/Home.htm" authentication-failure-url="/LoginFailed.htm" authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccessHandler"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/Login.htm" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
       <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
               users-by-username-query="select email_id, password, enabled from user_table where lower(email_id)=lower(?)"
               authorities-by-username-query="select ut.email_id, ur.authority from user_table ut, user_roles ur where ut.user_id=ur.user_id and lower(ut.email_id)=lower(?)"/>
       </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="loginSuccessHandler" class="loginsuccesshandler.LoginSuccessHandler"/>

    <global-method-security>
        <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* dao.*.*(..))" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    </global-method-security>

    <!--<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />-->
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An other way is to register an handler for the [`AuthenticationSuccessEvent`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/event/AuthenticationSuccessEvent.html).

```
    @Service
    public class UserService implements
                             ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
           String userName = ((UserDetails) event.getAuthentication().
                                                  getPrincipal()).getUsername();
           User user = this.userDao.findByLogin(userName);
           user.setLastLoginDate(new Date());
        }
   }
```

Comment: Does this require some XML configurations? The `onApplicationEvent()` method was never invoked, when I tried. Additionally, how is this `userDao` object available here? In this case, I don't know where actually the thing is to be implemented rather than how it is implemented.

Comment: Going through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/182203/1391249) answer, I have registered it in the `applicationContext.xml` file as a bean and the event triggered but I'm not sure how to make `userDao` available. Using `@Autowied`? When I tried to auto-wire, I received -  `An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext`

Comment: how you inject your dao is not the scope of this answer, but @Autowire should work. "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext" did you tryed to inject it?

Comment: I'm trying to autowire like - `@Autowired
    private UserSevice userSevice;` in the class that implements `ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent>`.

Comment: When I put a debugging statement like `System.out.println("userName = "+userSevice.getUser(userName).getFirstName());`, it fails with this message - `An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext` as soon as the submit button is pressed. When I remove this statement, the event is triggered and it works. Autowiring doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Add an System.out.println(event.getAuthentication()); -- if it is an shows up an anonymus user, than you have to filter out this event

Comment: `System.out.println(event.getAuthentication());` displays -

Comment: `org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@bad860a5: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffdaa08: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: AEE54A59C9181C05A176D12E27D88CB1; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN`

Comment: Both the username and the password in my database are `admin`.

Comment: "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext" -- This must come from some other part of the program, not from this event handler. Could you please add the complete stacktrace.

Comment: The exception is consumed under the hood. Therefore, it is not available. This messages is through `sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message`. I really don't know how to display the full exception stacktrace. Is it somehow possible to see the complete exception stacktrace?

Comment: When I comment this section `<global-method-security>...</global-method-security>` in my security config file, then it works as intended. So, it has to do with the method security. Regarding this, I have several questions in my mind. Is it possible to authenticate from this event when the global method security is enabled? Should/can DAO services **not** be used from this event, when the global method security is enabled...??? and alike...

Comment: Additionally, I originally declared all the DAO classes `final`. I have removed the `final` keyword and tried to use proxy. Accordingly, I have changed `<global-method-security>` to `<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">` but that didn't make any difference. The only thing that made it work is by commenting out this global method security in the security config file. Kindly, tell me the way to get around this.

Comment: Or Is it not possible at all to use DAO services from outside the controller classes which are annotated with `@Controller`, when the global method security is enabled? I'm fully confused.

Comment: @Tiny, please open an new question, with all relevant details. (You can additional refer this question). So every body can read it, and maybe someone else but me knows the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I have already posted such a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15500519/1391249).

Comment: You can invoke services, controllers, repositories in the same way with and without `<global-method-security>` enabled. But it looks like you have some method security constraint somewhere. And I guess this protected method is invoked BEFORE the user authentication is complete don.

Comment: I have closed this discussion by accepting your answer. Many thanks.

Comment: Just one thing. Are you using the Spring framework 3.2.0? Does it really work with this version? Until now, I couldn't find anything wrong anywhere in my original application. I could smell it like a jira issue in the version 3.2.0.

Comment: Just for completeness: An anonymous user suggested to use  the `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent` instead of `AuthenticationSuccessEvent`, unfortunately he direct edided the answer without any notice, so his edit was rejected because it modified the answer to much.

Comment: In my case, I was advised to use `@Component` annotation, but the reality is that `@Service` especialisation must be used. Thank you! @Ralph

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094174/how-to-change-update-column-name-in-table-using-mysql-workbench

Comment: @Llama - what is with this question?

Answer (score 7):

Why do not do it in authentication success handler directly?

```
public final class LoginSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler
{
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        String userName = authentication.getPrincipal().getName();
        this.userService.updateLastLoginDateForUserByName(userName);

        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN"))
        {
            response.sendRedirect("admin_side/Home.htm");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach worked but it failed to work with `ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent>` indicating - `An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext` while trying to autowire the `UserService` interface as Ralph's answer which I'm more interested in. Do you know why?

Comment: Strange. Make brekepoints in SecurityContextHolder class (clearContext(), getContext(), etc...) and debug it

Comment: @Tiny, same problem here with Ralph's solution. (I am a newbie!)

Comment: @Eric : I cannot clarify it but `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` is sufficient (as this answer indicates), if some operations need to be performed as soon as login is made successfully (I was more intersted in knowing why doesn't `ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent>` work after successful login as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15500519/1391249) question of mine indicates).

Answer (score 2):

You could also subclass the spring `AuthenticationProvider` interface and inject it into the `<authentication-manager />` element.

The class would be something like

```
public class AuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {

    // inject whatever tou want

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
                throws AuthenticationException {
            return super.authenticate(authentication);

            // do what ever you want here
    }

}
```

(supposing you're using `DaoAuthenticationProvider`)

Then you just need to register beans

```
<bean class="x.y.z.AuthenticationProvider" id="myAuthProvider" scope="singleton" />
<authentication-manager>
   <authentication-provider ref="myAuthProvider">
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
           users-by-username-query="select email_id, password, enabled from user_table where lower(email_id)=lower(?)"
           authorities-by-username-query="select ut.email_id, ur.authority from user_table ut, user_roles ur where ut.user_id=ur.user_id and lower(ut.email_id)=lower(?)"/>
   </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

(Don't trust code correctness, I wrote it on the fly. It's just meant to show my idea.)

Stefano