# Spring security last access time

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm starting with Spring Security and would like to know if it's possible to get the last access time of logged user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you will have to track that information. For example: [How to correctly update the login date time after successful login with Spring security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493237/how-to-correctly-update-the-login-date-time-after-successful-login-with-spring-s)

There is no out of the box feature provided by Spring security.

Comment: it works fine when user does login action, but I'm using the **Remember Me** feature , so I'd like to be notified on login AND on Rembember Me validation. Is it possible?

Comment: If you are using Spring Security version >= 3.1.x then you will be able to use authentication success handler for remember me. Please check: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-1603 and http://www.to-string.com/2012/07/11/springsecurity-capturing-rememberme-success-event/