# how to change (Update) column name in table using MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am new to MySQL. I created a table with column name `First Name` but it is wrong.

Now I want to change my column name `First Name` to `First_Name`. Is it possible? If yes please explain how I can change my column name.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can change it by following these step :

1. Right click the table shown at the left in `Schema` tab of workbench and then select `Alter Table`. You will get a window like this -> 
   [image]
2. Here you can see the column names available, edit here and click on apply.

You are done.

Comment: Your welcome, please upvote the post if it's helpful for you.

Comment: Which version it is? I dont get the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to change the column name.. For Example:-

```
ALTER TABLE customers RENAME COLUMN id TO Customer_ID;
```

Where, table name is customers and I'm changing old name `id` to new name `Customer_ID`.. below is the source from mysql wokbench:-

https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=10761

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit the Datatype too, you can do it very quickly by using an sql query :

```
ALTER TABLE `employee_directory`.`employee` CHANGE COLUMN `id_employee` `id_employee` BIGINT;
```

P.S. :

```
employee_directory = The DataBase name.  
employee = The table name.
id_employee = The column name.
```

See the image below for more information.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iASz.png)