# #SQL How can i change names of columns on my table?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

[image]
Please i need your help! i have import a table on MySQL Workbench, but i find that the names of the columns are not imputed correctly, they don't have the underscore, and when i try to run a query a have an error message.
Exemple " Movie Title "
when i try to make by exemple [ SELECT Movie Title From table ] it don't work.
How can i add "_" on columns to fix this problem ?
Thank you

Ihabe Kaine

I try run this code but it doesn't work !

```
ALTER TABLE movie_data.movie_data
rename column Movie Title TO Movie Title
```

I want just add underscore

Comment: You should be able to rename columns using the Workbench GUI tools, you don't need to do it with SQL.

Comment: how can i do it ! i'm stuck

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094174/how-to-change-update-column-name-in-table-using-mysql-workbench

Comment: It doesn't work, ok, but please don't leave out saying what *did* happen

Answer (score 1):

If a column name contains spaces you have to put it in backticks.

```
ALTER TABLE movie_data.movie_data
RENAME COLUMN `Movie Title` TO Movie_Title;
```

Comment: it doesn't worked also ! cod error : unknown column  `Movie_Title` in movie_data.movie_data.

Comment: Sorry I didn't put the space there.

Comment: it's worked with this code :  ALTER TABLE movie_data.movie_data
RENAME COLUMN `Movie Title` TO `Movie_Title`;         thank you so much for your help