# Cleanest way to call multiple AuthenticationSuccessHandlers?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a java webapp using Spring 3.1. My Spring security context defines multiple authentication filters, each corresponding to a different authentication path (e.g. username/password vs. Single Sign On). Each auth filter defines its own `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`. Now, I want to inject 2 additional actions to take upon successful authentication, and they should apply across *all* authentication types:

1. set a tracking event code for Google Analytics to use on the front-end
2. update the user's preferred locale in our database

These could be any actions that you want a hook for, after the user has been successfully authenticated. The important point is that, unlike the regular  AuthenticationSuccessHandlers (which are different for each authentication path), they don't forward or redirect the request. So it's safe to call a bunch of them.

**Is there a clean way to integrate these additional authentication success "actions", using Spring Web/Security 3.1?**

I looked into implementing an [`ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182160/spring-security-adding-on-successful-login-event-listener), but my events need to access the request, and all `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` provides is the `Authentication` object itself.

I couldn't find a way, so I decided to roll my own proxy:

```
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandlerProxy implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    private List<AuthenticationSuccessHandler> authenticationSuccessHandlers;

    public AuthenticationSuccessHandlerProxy(List<AuthenticationSuccessHandler> successHandlers) {
        this.authenticationSuccessHandlers = successHandlers;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        for (AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler : this.authenticationSuccessHandlers) {
            successHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking breafly into the source code of `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and all other places where `AuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(...)` is called I do not see any possibility to do it using Spring Security.

As a workaround you can try to wrap your success handlers into some AspectJ or AOP pointcut and then apply this pointcut to `AuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(...)` execution. Maybe like this you can target all authentication types.