# Spring security redirecting to a page after login using redirect: uri

Tags: grails, spring-security

From the `auth.gsp` page  i want redirect to `create.gsp` if the login is successful.In spring security how to do it?

redirect uri: "/user/create" in login Controller i tried this but after successful login it first go to the default uri then clicking on the login controller again only leads to the `create.gsp`.

Comment: AuthenticationSuccessHandler will work for this scenario.
Read about it.

Comment: I am a beginner to spring security. Can you suggest some tutorials for doing this.

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764580/handle-successful-login-event-with-spring-security/20765279#20765279 (possible duplicate)

Comment: Here is a good example for authentication success handler

http://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login

Comment: it really helped.. thanx Ravi kumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default spring security stores the request url you want to access before you are redirected to the login page. After you logged in successfully you are then redirected to the page you wanted.

E.g.

- user tried to access `/test`
- user not logged in -> redirect user to login page
- user successfully logged in -> redirect to `/test`

You can override this behaviour with the `successHandler.alwaysUseDefault` config property:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/your-url'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault = true
```