# Logging a user's login and logout activities

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, logback

I am new to Spring. I have a requirement to log all successful login and logout attempts by a user using logback.
I am using one HandleInterceptor(org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor) to intercept all requests made to handlers. 
Can I use the same interceptors to handle authentication requests too?
If not which interceptors to be used. Or is there any way around?

Answer (score 2):

As you are only interested in login and logout operation, you should not use a handler interceptor on all requests.

There is  a simple way to be notified all all login events : use an `ApplicationListener` that will listen to `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` or `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent` - you will find more details and example code on this other post [Spring security: adding “On successful login event listener”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182160/spring-security-adding-on-successful-login-event-listener)

To be notified on logout, you can use a custom `SuccessfullLogoutHandler` or add a `LogoutHandler` to the `LogoutFilter`. You can configure it with the `<logout>` attribute in xml configuration or with a `SecurityContextLogoutHandler` if you are using java configuration in spring security 3.2