# Spring MVC : Using User password to create a Java keystore, and access keys later

Tags: java, spring-mvc, encryption, spring-security, keystore

- I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which there is a Person
  class for whom I am storing the password in database with BCrypt
  format. Now, I would like to create a Java keystore using MD5 sum of
  the user's plaintext password.

  - But because I don't know how and where Spring-security is taking the plaintext password and doing a BCrypt on it to check vs the database, I am not able to use the plaintext password to create an MD5 sum.
  - And this process I would like to repeat everytime the user logs in so that I can unlock the keystore programmatically and retrieve the key with keyname and the MD5 sum as the password.

I am pasting my Person model and, spring-security-application.xml :

```
 @Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements UserDetails{

    private static final GrantedAuthority USER_AUTH = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");

    private static final String emailRegexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$";

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "person_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "person_seq_gen",sequenceName = "person_seq")
    private int id;

    @Valid
    @Email
    @Pattern(regexp = emailRegexp)
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Valid
    @NotEmpty(message = "Password may not be empty")
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;


 //getters and setters ommitted

}
```

PersonServiceImpl :

```
 @Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean addPerson(Person p) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Person existingUser = personDAO.findPersonByUsername(p.getUsername());
        if(existingUser == null) {
            this.personDAO.addPerson(p);
            p.setAccountstatus(false);
            p.setOnetimeemail(false);
            p.setUsername(p.getUsername().toLowerCase());
            p.setPassword(BCrypt.hashpw(p.getPassword(), BCrypt.gensalt(11)));
            p.setUsername(p.getUsername().toLowerCase());
            this.personDAO.addPerson(p);
            sendAccountActivationEmail(p.getUsername(), p.getFirstName());
            return true;
        } else {
            return  false;
        }
    }
```

security-applicationContext.xml :

```
 <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <security:http create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/canvas/list" always-use-default-target="false" authentication-failure-url="/denied.jsp" />
        <security:remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me" user-service-ref="userDetailsService" token-validity-seconds="1209600" data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
        <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>

<!--        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https"/> -->

  <!--  <security:port-mappings>
        <security:port-mapping http="80" https="443"/>
    </security:port-mappings>
-->
    </security:http>




    <!-- queries to be run on data -->
    <beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
        <beans:property name="key" value="_spring_security_remember_me" />
        <beans:property name="tokenRepository" ref="jdbcTokenRepository"/>
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!--Database management for remember-me -->
    <beans:bean id="jdbcTokenRepository"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl">
        <beans:property name="createTableOnStartup" value="false"/>
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Remember me ends here -->
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" erase-credentials="false">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="LoginServiceImpl">
           <security:password-encoder  ref="encoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="encoder"
                class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
                <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<security:http create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/canvas/list" always-use-default-target="false" authentication-failure-url="/denied.jsp" />
    <security:remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me" user-service-ref="userDetailsService" token-validity-seconds="1209600" data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
    <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
</security:http>

<beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <beans:property name="key" value="_spring_security_remember_me" />
    <beans:property name="tokenRepository" ref="jdbcTokenRepository"/>
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="jdbcTokenRepository"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl">
    <beans:property name="createTableOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</beans:bean>
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" erase-credentials="false">
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="LoginServiceImpl">
       <security:password-encoder  ref="encoder"/>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="encoder"
            class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
            class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
            <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
           <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
</beans:bean>
            <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

LoginServiceImpl :

```
@Transactional
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class LoginServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired private PersonDAO personDAO;
    @Autowired private Assembler assembler;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException,DataAccessException {
        Person person = personDAO.findPersonByUsername(username.toLowerCase());
            if(person == null) { throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Wrong username or password");} //Never specify which one was it exactly
        return assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(person);
    }

    public LoginServiceImpl() {
    }
}
```

Assembler :

```
@Service("assembler")
public class Assembler {
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    User buildUserFromUserEntity(Person userEntity){
        String username = userEntity.getUsername().toLowerCase();
        String password = userEntity.getPassword();

        boolean enabled = userEntity.isEnabled();
        boolean accountNonExpired = userEntity.isAccountNonExpired();
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = userEntity.isCredentialsNonExpired();
        boolean accountNonLocked = userEntity.isAccountNonLocked();

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        return new User(username,password,enabled,accountNonExpired,credentialsNonExpired,accountNonLocked,authorities);
        }
}
```

I hope what I said was clear, if there are any doubts, kindly let me know.. Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot... :-)

Comment: Look in the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.

Comment: @chrylis : Thanks, I am not implement UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. What should I do in that case? I looked it up, I believe you mean using public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY.

Comment: You're not *implementing* it. I said to look at it; that's where the code you're asking about is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let Spring Security keep the password in the session:

```xml
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" erase-credentials="false">
  <!-- authentication provider(s) -->
</authentication-manager>
```

Then you can retrieve the password by using:

```java
Authentication currentAuth = ...;
String pwd = currentAuth.getCredentials().toString();
```

To catch when user logins, you can [listen for AuthenticationSuccessEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182160/spring-security-adding-on-successful-login-event-listener).

Comment: Hello, I tried your code. I just used it in another method. I called  Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();, and then authentication.getCredentials.toString. I only got the username in return. Can you tell me what I should do to get the password as well.

Comment: @WeareBorg `getCredentials()` usually returns the password, but it may vary depending on configuration. Do you have something odd in your security config?

Comment: No, I am editing my post to paste full security-application-context.xml. I will also paste the Assembler and LoginServiceImpl which I use for findByUsername and build Entity. Kindly give me 5 mins. :-)

Comment: Done. Please have a look. :-)

Comment: It worked, I didn't even needed to extend the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. I just set false to erase credentials, and via authentication object I could get the password. Thanks a lot. :-)