# Why is my authentication object null despite the fact my authentication success handler is being called?

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, null, principal

I’m using Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE and Spring Security 3.1.4.RELEASE on JBoss WildFly 10.0.0.CR2.  I have the following set up in my application context …

```
<beans:bean id="springboardUsernamePasswordUrlAuthenticationFilter" class="org.mainco.subco.core.security.SubcoUsernamePasswordUrlAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:bean class="org.mainco.subco.myproject.security.SubcoAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login/failure"/>
            <beans:property name="userService" ref="userService" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property> 
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:bean class="org.mainco.subco.myproject.security.SubcoAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/success"/>
            <beans:property name="userService" ref="userService" />
            <beans:property name="sessionService" ref="sessionService" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>      
</beans:bean>
```

I notice when I type in an incorrect username/password combination, the failure handler is invoked, and when I enter in a correct username/password combination, the success handler is invoked, which ultimately calls the below method …

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/success")
public String authenticate(final Principal principal)
{
     …
}
```

This is configured in my web.xml.  Note that the Spring security filters catch the success URL in question …

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
   <filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

However, when the above method is called, the “principal” object is null, so I’m not able to figure out who is logged in.  What mechanism in Spring sets the Principal object upon successful login?  How can I figure out why I am seemingly able to login properly, but yet the authentication object is not set?

Comment: Try to get authentication object from SpringSecurityContext (use class `SpringSecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`), how does it look like?

Comment: This is not the soultion for your posted question, anyway: if you only want to do some action after the user logged in, then listen for the `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` or `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent` -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182160/spring-security-adding-on-successful-login-event-listener

Comment: @Jacek, The The SecurityContextHolder.getCOntext().getAuthentication() object returns null despite the fact the "authenticationSuccessHandler" method has a non-null Authentication object when its "onAuthenticationSuccess" method is called.  To Ralph, if I were to go with your solution, what would I put in the "defaultTargetUrl" of my authentication success handler?

Comment: If after the process of logging in your authentication object is still null, then it is a problem with your security flow. Username and password should be set in `loadUserByUsername(Strin username)` in `UserDetailsService`. Could you provide whole security configuration?

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue?